# How to echo value from slider range jquery when submit form And How to set value of slider range from $_GET value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

How to echo value from slider range jquery when submit form And How to set value of slider range from `$_GET` value ?

.....................................................................................................................................................................

first , How to echo value from slider range after press submit button (using php tag)

EG;

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        echo 2 value from slider range
    }
?>
```

this fiddle url

http://jsfiddle.net/peap/suk1rcrk/1/

second ,

How to set value of slider range from `$_GET` value

EG;

```
www.xxxx.com/yyy.php?first=50&second=700
```

When i get `$_GET` value like above url, i want to set slider range like this

http://image.ohozaa.com/i/102/FtG0n3.jpg

How can i do ?

Thank you every answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

_1.

in html form set hidden form fields (first, second) to pass data from js, in js get data from slider (ui.values[0] ui.values[1]) and pass them to hidden form fields, on server side get that data using $_GET or $_POST, for example $_GET['first']

_2.

```
<?php

$first = 90;
$second = 290;

if(empty($_GET['first']) === false) {
    $first = (int) $_GET['first'];
}

if(empty($_GET['second']) === false) {
    $second = (int) $_GET['second'];
}

?>


<script>
    $(function(){

        $('#rangeslider').slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 1000,
        values: [ <?php echo $first ?>, <?php echo $second ?> ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#rangeval').html(ui.values[0]+" - "+ui.values[1]);
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your fiddle to this: http://jsfiddle.net/suk1rcrk/2/

There's a hidden input form that stores the default slider range and is updated by jQuery on slider move with:

```
$('#rangeValue').val(ui.values[0]+" - "+ui.values[1]);
```

When submiting the form the value can be called upon by:

```
$_POST['rangeValue'];
```